# Can I obtain different results from iterative and recurive functions?

Tags: c++, recursion, sequence, numerical-computing

My code is supposed to calculate the 100th element of the sequence `$x_0=1 ;  x_i=\dfrac{x_{i-1}+1}{x_{i-1}+2}, i=1,2, \ldots$`

I wrote iterative and recursive functions, but the results are not equal. Is it due to the lost of decimals?

Here is my driver code. The data from the file is i=100.

```
int main()
{
    int i;

    ifstream f ("data.txt");
    f >> i;

    double x_0= 1.00;

    double x_100 = l(x_0, i);

    ofstream g ("results.txt", ios::app);
    g <<"\n100th element (by looping): " << x_100;

    x_100 = r(x_0);
    g <<"\n100th element (by recursion): " << x_100;

 
   return 0;
}
```

`l()` is iterative function,
`r()` is recursive function

```
double l(double x, int i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j<i ; j++){
            x = (x + 1)/(x+2);
    }
    return x;

}

double r(double x)
{
    if (x == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return (r(x-1) + 1) / (r(x-1) + 2);
}
```

Here are the results

```
100th element (by looping): 0.618034
100th element (by recursion): 0.666667
```

Comment: Yes, if the code is not written to produce identical observable behaviour.

Comment: `r` can't be right. It doesn't mention `100` anywhere. It just runs the recursion until the sequence converges all the way to `0`, so nested calls always return `1`, and the top-level call returns `(1 + 1) / (1 + 2) == 2/3 == 0.666666`. This is what you observe.

Comment: any recursive algorithm can be written as an iterative one : any obeserved differences thus are the result of bugs.

Comment: ...Neither does `l(x, i)` contain `100`. `l(x, i)` seems to calculate the `i`th element of the sequence not the 100th (allthough `i` is set to 100 here). That parameter is missing entirely on `r(x)`.

Comment: It looks like you're confusing the elements of the sequence with their indices; the initial value for `x` is 1.0, but you're comparing it to (the index) 0 to determine when to stop.

Comment: I have fixed the bug.  I realized I was passing the wrong argument as @IgorTandetnik remarked. The problem now is that it is slow. For the 20 th element, function r() took 5 seconds! I tried 100 th but it simply does not finish the calculation.

Comment: It's running in exponential time, since you compute the same value `r(x-1)` twice (and then each of those calls in turn makes 2 recursive calls, and those each make another two, ...) Call `r(x-1)` once, save the result in a local variable, use that variable when computing division.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I the recursive function you do

```
(r(x-1) + 1) / (r(x-1) + 2)
```

With `x == 1.0` that's equal to

```
(r(1-1) + 1) / (r(1-1) + 2)
```

That's of course equal to

```
(r(0) + 1) / (r(0) + 2)
```

And since `r(0)` will return `1` that equation is

```
(1.0 + 1) / (1.0 + 2)
```

There's no further recursion. The result is `2.0 / 3.0` which is `0.66667`.

The iterative function `l` on the other hand will do `100` iterations where each iteration will change the value of `x`, making it even smaller and smaller.

The functions simply does different things, leading to different results.